# Multiple emails for each Step of an Approval Process

Tags: email-template, approval-process

I would like to have custom emails sent out for each step of an Approval Process. The emails need to have different verbiage based upon the Step. I was thinking of using an Approval Assignment Template and then using a formula field which would be programmed to different verbiage based on the Status of the request. That seems like such a convoluted method. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Maybe set an Email Notification on each Step? Have you tried that?

Comment: That was my initial thought, but if I were to do that wouldn't the assignees get two emails - one as the standard approval process email, and the other from my Email Alert ?

Comment: have you tried a visualforce email template?  i believe they can be used for approvals but have not tested.  that would give you some more flexibility, perhaps w a custom component that could select which template to use based on the parameters you are after.  but it does require some more lift.

Comment: I think I'm going to go w/ the formula field idea (Email_Body__c). One template, different email verbiage based on field values.  Thanks everybody.